# How can I assemble a Laptop from parts

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, motherboard

Yesterday, I had the privilege of opening and upgrading the RAM of a P4 computer a relative had assembled from scratch. Thats when this weird thought occurred to me: Why can't I assemble a laptop in a manner similar to a standard desktop computer? What exactly stops the assembling of a laptop from scratch?

My search let me to this [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1657736&page=2) which nicely explains that this is not possible due to lack of standards in the laptop world. For instance, there is the [Atx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atx) standard which is universal for desktop motherboards. A poster proposes a hypothetical Ltx standard for laptops:

> Let's break LTX down into a few sizes, for displays. your basic LTX
>   case comes with a power supply, a display, and cords. the display size
>   dictates the exact LTX size. so, a 14 inch display would be LTX-14.
>   tentatively, lets start with -8, -14, -17, and -22.
>
> LTX-14 motherboards would be required to fit into an LTX-17, but not
>   the other way around for obvious reasons. if you wanted to (for
>   whatever reason), you could put something together using standard
>   components that is only slightly more expensive than a current
>   netbook, and has a 22 inch display. put a LTX-9 ATOM motherboard into
>   a LTX-22 case.
>
> MicroLTX would be similar, but not have space for a separate laptop
>   video card (o yes, we are standardizing laptop video cards, too) and
>   perhaps top off at two RAM slots. MicroLTX motherboards fit into LTX
>   cases, but not the other way around.
>
> all connectors pertaining to the display, power, etc, would be
>   identical. individual case OEM's can use different hinges to attach
>   the display to the base and whatnot, but the wiring all needs to be
>   identical.

Leaving aside the topic of standards, is it possible for an average John Doe like me to assemble a laptop from scratch in a cost effective manner? If yes, then how do I go about it?

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please give a constructive reason so that the issue may be addressed or corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed build your own laptop. It might be slightly more complicated than building a desktop, but not horribly more difficult. It probably won't be much cheaper than buying a pre-built laptop, and you won't have the wide range of hardware options and customization options you'd get with a desktop, because there aren't a lot of people who want to build their own laptops, and because the OEMs can order components custom designed to allow them unique construction arrangements in their laptops.

While I build all my own desktops, I have never considered building my own laptop for these preceding reasons.

However, if you want to go about building one, finding compatible components will be the first and most important step. Check out guides such as this one from Computer Shopper as a starting place: http://www.computershopper.com/feature/build-your-own-laptop

Comment: "With a thirst for challenge and a $1,400 budget..." - That sounds like it would be costlier than getting it straight from the OEMs, not very encouraging!

Comment: @PrahladYeri - Who said it was going to be inexpensive?  The major problem you have is finding the motherboard, they are not sold by retail consumers.  Then of course your limited to mobile CPU products which are also not sold by retail to consumers.  Lets not even get started with the display that isn't sold to consumers normally.  You really have an up hill battle.

Comment: @Ramhound - Why is it that some laptop parts aren't sold to consumers directly. Is it because OEMs don't want consumers to assemble themselves and hence put such regulations? Or there isn't any market for individual parts to begin with?

Comment: @PrahladYeri - Contact an OEM and ask.  I would imagine historically and still is a cost per volume problem.  Its cheap(er) to get 100,000 displays compared to a single display.  You can find sources for these, clearly new "OEMS" have come to market new laptops, but they purchase in huge volumes.

Comment: Prahlad, if you take apart 10 different laptops, you'll find 10 completely and entirely different sets of hardware. Yes, they all have the same basic components, but they are different shapes, sizes, arrangements. This is done because people who want laptops usually value things like size and weight more than accessibility or power. So the OEMs order very unique parts to build their systems with. Because of this variety, the only "standardized" components are those for the extremely small group of people who want to build their own. No market, no savings.